# Where are Windows 10 Cortana reminders stored in the cloud?

Tags: windows, cortana

Is there a way to access the Cortana reminders one makes in Windows 10 programatically? Evidently the reminders are cloud based as they sync with Windows 10 Mobile devices. Which api exposes the reminders tied to a specific Microsoft account? My google-fu has failed me so far

Comment: I don't believe there's currently a way to do this, probably because it requires careful privacy considerations. Are you looking for an API to add your own reminders, or just to enumerate the ones that already exist?

Comment: I was looking to retrieve/modify/add/delete time and place reminders for an authenticated user.

Comment: Okay, checked with the team here, there's currently no supported way for developers to do what you're asking, but I've also passed along your interest in there being a way to do it. Unfortunately, I can't give you any kind of timeline for when it might become available either.